# Merging two data.tables results in data.table of only one repetitive merge factor

Tags: r, merge, data.table, vlookup

I am merging a single column dt with a helper table dt, to eventually be added to a larger dt.

My data.table named "full" is a wide and long data.table, of which I am selecting column "category_product" which is a series of categories of snacks. I copied full$category_product to its own dt.

Helper1 is a dt that has each category of snack listed once, along with a column of the name of the snack and a number associated. I need to do this VLOOKUP style so that the name of each snack and number is listed down the categories.

The line I'm using is this and its variations is:

```
helper_categories = merge(assist1, helper1)
```

This is my process:

```
assist1 = data.table(full$category_product)
setnames(assist1, old = c('V1'),new = c('category_product'))
assist1[] <- lapply(assist1, as.character)
helper_categories = merge(assist1, helper1)
```

My assist1 table (is over 1 million rows long but) looks like:

```
assist1 = data.table(category_product = 'Salty','Water','Juice, tea and smoothies')
```

And my complete helper1 table looks like:

```
helper1 = data.table(
category_product = c('Sugar candy','Cookies, pastries and cereals','Chocolate based','Salty','Juice, tea and smoothies','Carbonates and energy drinks','Water','Milk based'), 
ph1 = c('sugar_confectionary_incl_gums_1','bakery_and_pastries_1','chocolate_based_9','salty_excl_crisps_4','tea_and_coffee_based_4','unflavoured_carbonates_3','water_(flavoured)_2','milk_and_milk-based_4'),
mh1 = c(2.054545,2.618182,2.172727,2.963636,3.136364,2.390909,3.154545,2.936364))
```

However, the results I'm getting when I open helper_categories is just a data.table with 'Carbonates and energy drinks' and its info repeated over and over and over again. It looks like this:

```
helper_categories = data.table(category_product = rep('Carbonates and energy drinks', 20), ph1 = rep('unflavoured_carbonates_3', 20), mh1 = rep(2.390909, 20)
```

Any idea what's going on or how to fix it? I adjusted the class of the common column to be character as I thought that could be it, but to no avail.

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: A VLOOKUP style result. I need a table that has all the categories of assist1 with their respective ph1 and mh1 next to it.

Comment: there is a typo in your `assist1`. you are missing a `c()`. this should be what you are looking for: `assist1[helper1, on=.(category_product), c("ph1","mh1") := .(i.ph1, i.mh1)]`